# Selenium python wait after clicking

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I try to wait after clicking on **scraping** script Selenium in Python but it doesn't work.

I work on pogs-backoffice website

I need to change filter bar conditions

I click on first condition and page is loading next view but my script continue and click on second option which is not ready for the first condition, so my script crash :/

```
# First filter bar conditions click
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a/img"))).click()

# Second click
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[5]"))).click()
```

Do you have a solution to wait action back on first click please ?

I already try Wait.Until on element visible after first click, and javascript document.isreayd function but it doesn't work :/
Sleep break my script and my driver so it doesn't work too

I dont know how to do

Sorry for my english, I'm french

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps

```
# First filter bar conditions click
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div["
                                                                      "2]/a/img"))).click()
timeout = 30
try:
    element_present = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[5]"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present).lick() # click if found
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present).click()  # Second click wait for more time
```

Comment: it doesn't work but i found a strange solution with fluentWaiter. Howerver, the process takes more and more time after x executions :/